# Cannot get kubectl logs on worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I created a cluster of k8s consisting of one master node and three worker nodes. (master node can do master and worker role). Everything was good. I can deploy pod, exec pod, get logs... but I have some log problem. I cannot get logs from worker node. I only get logs from master node `kubeclt logs <pod-name>`

This is my error msg:

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials ( pods/log nginx))
```

It occurred only worker node scheduled pod. Help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your master node check kubelet logs

```
journalctl -u kubelet
```

There you might see something like

```
Flag --some-flag has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag
```

Remove those flags  and put it into the kubelet config file `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`

Also the default Authentication and Authorization to Kubelet's API differs between cli args and config files, so you should make sure to set the "legacy defaults" in the config file to preserve existing behavior.

Here is the snippet of my config.yaml

```
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false #set true to enable
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 2m0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 5m0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 30s
```

Comment: Thanks for your mention! but, how to remove deprecated flag? i found "--cgroup-driver has been deprecated" but i could not see this flag in config.yaml file. is there any remove command?

Comment: @WOOJINNA `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` pointing to `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`

Comment: i solved this problem. it because my company proxy environment. so i added my worker node's ip to no_proxy setting to kube-apiserver.yml. and now i can get logs from worker node's pod.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the worker nodes IP's in no_proxy on kube-apiserver.yaml im able to succesfully view logs